# Pythagorean Theorem test not working?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

So I'm trying to write a program that loops through every possible combination of side lengths for 3 sides of a triangle, and prints the ones that follow the Pythagorean Theorem (i.e., sideA(sqr) + sideB(sqr) = hypotenuse(sqr) ). The ones that match, it's supposed to print. However the math isn't executing the way it should. The issue I think lies with how I set up my loops.

My question then is, how should I set this up? Because I was under the impression that for loops execute in the following manner:

The outermost loop would check if the pythagorean condition is satisfied. If it is, it prints the result, increments, and tests again. When the condition isn't satisfied, it would transfer to the 2nd for loop where the same process repeats, at which point the 2nd loop transfers to the 3rd, innermost for loop. There, it would increment all the way to 500, testing and printing every applicable result, and once that was done, it would transfer back out to the middle loop. The middle loop increments, tests again, and once the condition doesn't check out, the code transfers to the innermost loop and the process repeats, only this time the middle loop variable is changed (i.e., new sets of numbers are being tested.) The whole process repeats until the 2nd for loop has incremented all the way to 500, at which point it transfers to the outermost loop, aand the process repeats all over. The outermost loop increments until the condition is no longer satisfied, then it transfers to the middle loop, and the 2 inner loops go through their procedure once again only this time with a changed outer for loop variable (i.e. testing new possibilities once again).

any and all help on this would be appreciated. I would love to move on, but I feel like this concept of nested looping is really key to understand and I don't want to sell myself short on this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {

    int sideA = 1;
    int sideB = 1;
    int hypotenuse = 1;

    for (hypotenuse = 1; hypotenuse <= 500; hypotenuse++) {
        if ( (hypotenuse * hypotenuse) == ( sideA * sideA + sideB * sideB) ) {
            printf("%d, %d, %d\n", sideA, sideB, hypotenuse);
        }

        else {
            for (sideA = 1; sideA <= 500; hypotenuse++) { 
                if ( (hypotenuse * hypotenuse) == ( sideA * sideA + sideB * sideB) ) {
                    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", sideA, sideB, hypotenuse);
                }

                else {
                    for (sideB = 1; sideB <= 500; sideB++) {
                        if ( (hypotenuse * hypotenuse) == ( sideA * sideA + sideB * sideB) ) {
                            printf("%d, %d, %d\n", sideA, sideB, hypotenuse);
                        }      
                    }   
                }
            }           
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: Putting logic for testing at each level of the loop is not the best way to do this - instead, nest your loop's 3 levels and check within the inner-most loop instead.

Comment: ..and you don't need the third inner loop at all. It's 100% determined by the first two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typo at `for (sideA = 1; sideA <= 500; hypotenuse++)`.

Also, excessive number of ifs, you dont need any of that.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int sideA, sideB, hypotenuse;

    for (hypotenuse = 1; hypotenuse <= 500; hypotenuse++)
        for (sideA = 1; sideA <= 500; sideA++)
            for (sideB = 1; sideB <= 500; sideB++)
                if ((hypotenuse * hypotenuse) == (sideA * sideA + sideB * sideB))
                    printf("%d, %d, %d\n", sideA, sideB, hypotenuse);
}
```

http://ideone.com/P01jxB

In addition, observe that some behaviours will be happening in your code:

1. After first loop, `sideA` and `sideB` used by the first `if` won't be `1` anymore, they might even be out of bound (501).
2. If the logic falls on any of those `if`s, you won't be running the tests for the other values.

As for the performance, notice that this nested loop is running a total of **125 million** times (500 * 500 * 500). This could be optimized in many ways, including by using a couple functions of the lib you included but are not using, `math.h`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a, b;
    for (a = 1; a <= 500; a++)
        for (b = a; b <= 500; b++) // b starts from a, not 1
        {
            double h = sqrt(a * a + b * b);

            if (h > 500.0) // hypotenus is bigger than 500, stop the loop
                break;

            if (fmod(h, 1) == 0.0) // only print if hypotenuse is an integer value
            {
                printf("%d, %d, %d\n", a, b, (int)h);
                printf("%d, %d, %d\n", b, a, (int)h); // print both ways around, optional
            }
        }
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/DZFa3s

This should reproduce the same result (not in the same order though), and much faster, running only a total of approximately 98 thousand loops.

Comment: It could be more efficient with `for (sideA = 1; sideA < hypotenuse; sideA++) for (sideB = hypotenuse-sideA; sideB < hypotenuse; sideB++)` but +1.

Comment: @WeatherVane Even more if it just calculated the hypotenuse from `sideA` and `sideB`, its also implicit that inverting `sideA` and `sideB` will give the same result for hypotenuse, but all those optimizations are not part of the immediate problem.

Comment: I would do the integer test a bit differently: `int s1 = a*a + b*b, h1 = int(0.5 + sqrt((double)s1); if (h1 * h1 == s1) ...`

Comment: Man my business was messy... thanks a lot for the help guys, its much appreciated. Its all actually very straight forward and simple now.